# Como acceder a la columna de una tabla relacionada por clave foránea en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Buenas a todos, tengo un pequeño problema que me tiene frito, expongo un poco primero para poner en antecedente, mi aplicacion gestiona las vacaciones de trabajadores, entonces tengo el modelo worker, que extiende de user, y el modelo vacaciones:

```
class Vacation extends Model
{
    public function worker(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Worker','worker_id');
    }
}
```

y modelo worker:

```
class Worker extends User
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'worker_id';

    public function area(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
    }

    public function vacations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vacation');
    }
}
```

el metodo del controlador:

```
public function solicitudes()
    {
        $vacations = Vacation::with(array('worker'))->get();
        //$vacations = Vacation::where('aceptado',0);
        return view('vacation.showvac')->with('vacations', $vacations->get());
    }
```

la linea comentada es por lo que filtro las solicitudes que no estan aprobadas, pero cuando intento imprimir la informacion de la tabla vacaciones, obtengo el worker_id, que es la clave foranea que relaciona a vacaciones con la tabla workers, mi problema es que cuando lo intento llamar en el controlador, me sale este error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'workers.worker_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `workers` where `workers`.`worker_id` in (1, 2))
```

lo cual ya me empieza a retrasar bastante siendo algo tan "simple", pero no soy capaz de imprimir el nombre del trabajador en vez del id que es mi intencion, he visto y leido mucho por google y asi pero la verdad ninguna de las soluciones aportadas me ayudan, igual estoy haciendo algo mal y no me doy cuenta.
Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es porque el modelo busca una tabla workers que no existe ya que al parecer estas extendiendo de User.

Lo que puedes hacer para resolverlo es crear la tabla workers o decirle a ese modelo que use la de User; mediante la propiedad table.

class Worker extends User
{

```
protected $table = 'users';

protected $primaryKey = 'worker_id';

public function area(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
}

public function vacations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vacation');
}
```

}

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero workers tiene su propia tabla, es cierto que es redundante la tabla workers, porque podria tener los parametros en users, de eso ya me di cuenta, pero aunque pusiera eso como tu dices todo en user, o en worker me devuelve el mismo error, o object non-type, con lo cual mi problema pienso que es lo que dice Jean, tengo que hacer el inner join, pero bueno muchas gracias de verdad :D

Answer (score 0):

lo que tendrías que hacer es un inner join, laravel te ayuda con query builder [aquí esta la documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)

Answer (score 0):

en cuanto al error que obtienes parece ser porque no existe la columna worker_id o bien directamente no existe la tabla. Deberías chequear esto, pero estimo que si la tabla existe deberías tener una columna worker_id. De todas formas el error te dice que no existe la columna.

En cuanto a la forma de acceder al nombre del registro de worker relacionado con Vacations deberías escribir el siguiente código suponiendo que la tabla worker tiene una columna worker_name:

```
$vacations->worker->worker_name
```

Espero que te sirva, pero asegurate de haber creado la tabla worker en base de datos.

Comment: gracias por tu aclaracion si que esta creada, pero veo que cuando hace el select esta haciendolo a alguna columna que no es la correcta y creo que es porque no estoy codificando bien mi metodo de solicitudes.

Answer (score 0):

Para algun otro usuario que pueda acabar en este post buscando algo parecido a lo mio, efectivamente Jean tenia razón, necesitaba hacer un inner join para obtener los nombres de los trabajadores en mi consulta, muchas gracias Jean, ahora solo me falta saber como mostrarlos en la vista jeje.

Un saludo a todos y gracias por la ayuda

```
  DB::table('workers')->select('workers.name')
->join('vacations','vacations.worker_id','=','workers.id');
```